# Matrix elements of Tenser force $S_{12}$ in Spin-dependent Nucleon-Nucleon Interactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics

I am aware of the fact, that the matrix elements of the tensor operator $$S_{12}= 3( \boldsymbol{\sigma}_1 \cdot \hat{\mathbf r})(\boldsymbol{\sigma}_2 \cdot \hat{\mathbf r}) - \boldsymbol{\sigma}_1 \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}_2, \quad \hat{\mathbf{r}} = \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}$$
can be calculated via the Wigner-Eckart theorem. The exercise (see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNoZv.png)) implies, that there is another way to do that. The steps (a), (b), (c), (e) are clear for me. I struggle with (d) and (f). Before i ask my questiens to these parts, I summarize my solution for (a), (b), (c), (e) shortly:

The simultaneous eigenfunctions (or eigenstates) of $\mathbf J^2$, $J_z$, $\mathbf S^2$ and $\mathbf L^2$ are
\begin{align}
| \mathscr{Y}_{L,S,J}^M \rangle &= |LS;JM \rangle = \sum_{m_L=-L}^L \sum_{\sigma=-S}^S |LS;m_L\sigma \rangle \underbrace{C_{LS; m_L\sigma}^{JM }}_{\text{C. G. - coefficients}} \\
\Rightarrow \mathscr{Y}_{L,S,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) &= \langle \hat{\mathbf{r}}(\theta,\varphi)| \mathscr{Y}_{L,S,J}^M \rangle =\sum_{m_L=-L}^L \sum_{\sigma=-S}^S Y_L^{m_L}(\theta,\varphi)|S\sigma \rangle  C_{LS; m_L\sigma}^{JM} .
\end{align}

Solution (a): Write $S_{12}$ as $2(3Q-\mathbf{S}^2)$, where $\mathbf{S} = 1/2(\boldsymbol{\sigma}_1 +\boldsymbol{\sigma}_2)$ is the total spin, and $Q=(\mathbf{S} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}})^2$. Because the quadratic norm of the vector $\mathbf{S}|00\rangle$ vanishes
$$
\langle00|\mathbf{S}^2|00\rangle = 0,
$$ $\mathbf{S}|00\rangle$ vanishes, too. $\Rightarrow Q|00\rangle =0,S_{12}|00\rangle =0$.

Solution (b): $[\mathbf L^2,S_{12}]\ne 0$, but $[P,S_{12}]=0$ ( $P$ is the parity operator). Hence, the eigenstates of $S_12$ can be found among the simultaneous eigenfunctions of $\mathbf J^2$, $J_z$, $\mathbf S^2$ and $P$ (we replaced $\mathbf L^2$ with $P$). For $S=1$ (Spin - Triplett) and $P=(-1)^J$, we have $L=J$ (because of the spherical harmonics). In this case
$
\mathcal{Y}_{J,1,J}^M
$
is a possible eigenfunction of $S_{12}$.
$$
S_{12}\mathscr{Y}_{J,1,J}^M = a_{J,J} \mathscr{Y}_{J,1,J}^M
$$
For $S=1$ and $P=(-1)^{J+1}$ the eigenfunction is a superposition of $L=J+1$- and $L=J-1$-states. For $L=J\pm 1$, $S_{12}$ "couples" these states:
$$
S_{12}\mathscr{Y}_{L,1,J}^M = a_{L,J+1} \mathscr{Y}_{J+1,1,J}^M + a_{L,J-1} \mathscr{Y}_{J-1,1,J}^M.
$$

Solution (c): Showing, that $[\mathbf{J},S_{12}]=0$ is straight foreward. And than it is obvious I think.

Solution (e): Just use the "north pole formular" for spherical harmonics
$$
Y_{l}^m(\theta=0,\varphi)=Y_{l}^m(\hat{\mathbf{e}}_z) = \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}} \delta_{m0}
$$
and $Q \big \vert_{\theta=0} = S_z^2$.

Question to (d):
$$\begin{align} a_{J+1,J-1} &= \langle \mathscr{Y}_{J+1,1,J}^M|S_{12}| \mathscr{Y}_{J-1,1,J}^M \rangle \\ a_{J-1,J+1} &= \langle \mathscr{Y}_{J-1,1,J}^M|S_{12}| \mathscr{Y}_{J+1,1,J}^M \rangle\end{align}
$$
I can only see from this, that the constants are respectively complex conjugate: $$a_{J+1,J-1} = a_{J-1,J+1}^*.$$ Did i miss something?

Question to (f): What do they mean with $\hat{\mathbf r} = \hat{\mathbf{k}}$ ??

If someone has annotations or questions, feel free to comment :-). I sincerely thank those who can help me with my questions.

[image: Exercise Taken from: Donnelly, T., Formaggio, J., Holstein, B., Milner, R., & Surrow, B. (2017). Foundations of Nuclear and Particle Physics. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/9781139028264]

This is taken from: Donnelly, T., Formaggio, J., Holstein, B., Milner, R., & Surrow, B. (2017). Foundations of Nuclear and Particle Physics. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/9781139028264
Url: https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/foundations-of-nuclear-and-particle-physics/779E1C84B94FD01E4B43500AA84C8703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I finished the whole problem by myself. In part (f) one has to consider $\theta=0$ again and then, because $\mathbf J$ commutes with $S_{12}$, one can consider the special cases $M\in \{-1,0,1\}$. For those who came accross to the same problem, I will give a complete solution of the problem in follwing:

To determine the radial equation for a Hamiltonian, that contains a tensor force term
\begin{align}
V_T(r)S_{12}
\end{align}
we have to evaluate how $S_{12}$ acts on $\lvert LS;JM\rangle$ directly.
Depending on the value of $S$ we have to classify the values after the parity. To do this, we consider
\begin{align}
 \mathscr Y_{L,S,J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi)
 &= \langle\hat{\mathbf n}(\theta,\varphi)\vert LS;JM \rangle \notag \\ 
 &= \sum_{m_l=-L}^L \sum_{\sigma=-S}^S  \langle\hat{\mathbf n}(\theta,\varphi)\vert LS;m_L \sigma \rangle C_{LS;m_L \sigma}^{JM} \notag \\
 &=  \sum_{m_l=-L}^L \sum_{\sigma=-S}^S  Y_L^{m_L}(\theta,\varphi) \vert S \sigma\rangle C_{LS;m_L \sigma}^{JM}  \notag \\
 &=  \sum_{\sigma=-S}^S  Y_L^{m_L}(\theta,\varphi) \vert S \sigma\rangle C_{LS;m_L \sigma}^{JM} ,
\end{align}
and use, that the parity of the spherical harmonics $Y_L^{m_L}(\theta,\varphi)$ is $(-1)^L$.

The functions $\mathscr{Y}_{L,S,M}^{M}(\theta,\varphi)$ are eigenfunctions of $\mathbf S^2$, thus, in order to determine the action of $S_{12}$, it is sufficient to determine the action of $Q=(\mathbf S \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}})^2$ on these functions. If $S=0$, then necessarily $L=J$ (therefor the parity is $(-1)^J$) and $\mathscr{Y}_{J0J}^{J}(\theta,\varphi) = Y_J^{M}(\theta,\varphi) \vert 00\rangle$ is necessarily an eigenfunction of $Q$. The quadratic norm $\langle 00|\mathbf S^2|00\rangle$ of $\mathbf S |S=0,M_S=0\rangle$ vanishes. Therefore $\mathbf S|00\rangle$ vanishes, too. Consequently, it results,
\begin{align}
 Q\mathscr{Y}_{J0J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) =QY_J^{M}(\theta,\varphi) |00\rangle = 0.
\end{align}
If $S=1$ there are two possible values for the parity $(-1)^J$ and $(-1)^{J+1}$. In the first case, necessarily $L=J$ holds, and $ \mathscr{Y}_{J1J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi)$ is eigenfunction of $Q$
\begin{align}
 Q\mathscr{Y}_{J1J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) = C_{J}^{M} \mathscr{Y}_{J1J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi).
\end{align}
For the second case, the only possible values of $L$ are $J\pm1$ (unless $J=0$, in which case there is Just one value $J=1$) so that the eigenfunctions are of the form
\begin{align}
 R_{J-1}^{M}(r) \mathscr Y_{J-}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) + R_{J+1}^{M}(r) \mathscr Y_{J+}^{M}(\theta,\varphi),
\end{align}
where $ \mathscr Y_{J\pm}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) = \mathscr{Y}_{J\pm1,1,J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi)$. In other words, $Q$ couples $L = J \pm1 $ states:
\begin{align}
 Q \mathscr{Y}_{J+}^{M} (\theta,\varphi) &= D_{J+1\,J+1}^{M} \mathscr Y_{J+}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) + D_{J+1\,J-1}^{M} \mathscr Y_{J-}^{M}(\theta,\varphi)\\
 Q \mathscr{Y}_{J-}^{M} (\theta,\varphi) &= D_{J-1\,J+1}^{M} \mathscr Y_{J+}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) + D_{J-1\,J-1}^{M} \mathscr Y_{J-}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) 
\end{align}
Because $J_z$ commutes with $Q$, the constants $\{C_{J}^{M}, D_{J\pm1\,J\pm1}^{M}, D_{J\mp1\,J\pm1}^{M}\}$ and the radial functions are independent of $M$. I.e.
\begin{align}
  D_{J\pm1\,J\pm1} &= \int \mathrm{d} \Omega \mathscr Y_{J\pm}^{M*}(\theta,\varphi) Q \mathscr Y_{J\pm}^{M}(\theta,\varphi), \label{constantD:a}  \\
  D_{J\pm1\,J\mp1} &= \int \mathrm{d} \Omega  \mathscr Y_{J\mp}^{M*}(\theta,\varphi) Q \mathscr Y_{J\pm}^{M}(\theta,\varphi). \label{constantD:b}
\end{align}
But since $Q$ is hermitean ($Q^\dagger = (\hat{\mathbf n} \cdot \mathbf S)^2 = Q$, because $[\hat{\mathbf n},\mathbf S] = 0$), both integrals on the right side of the first equation above are real valued, and the integrals on the right sides of the second equation are respectively complex conJugates, i.e. $D^*_{J+1J-1} = D_{J-1J+1}$.

Now we calculate the constants $\{C_{J}, D_{J\pm1J\pm1}, D_{J\mp1J\pm1}\}$. With the "north pole formula" of the spherical harmonics, we can derive $Q\mathscr{Y}_{J1J}^{M}(\theta=0,\varphi)$:
\begin{align}
 Q \mathscr{Y}_{L1J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) \bigg\vert_{\theta = 0} &= (\mathbf S \cdot \hat{\mathbf e}_z)^2 \mathscr{Y}_{L1J}^{M}(\theta=0,\varphi) \notag \\
 &= \sum_{\sigma=-1}^1  Y_J^{M-\sigma}(\theta=0,\varphi) \sigma^2 |1 \sigma\rangle C_{L1;M-\sigma\, \sigma}^{JM} \notag \\
 &= \sum_{\sigma=-1}^1  \sigma^2 \sqrt{\dfrac{2L+1}{4 \pi}} \delta_{M-\sigma0}|1 \sigma\rangle C_{L1;M-\sigma\, \sigma}^{JM} \notag \\
 &= \sqrt{\dfrac{2L+1}{4 \pi}}M^2|1 M\rangle C_{L1;0 1}^{JM}
\end{align}
Similary, we calculate $\mathscr{Y}_{L1J}^{M}(\theta=0,\varphi)$:
\begin{align}
 \mathscr{Y}_{L1J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) \bigg\vert_{\theta = 0} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2L+1}{4 \pi}}|1 M\rangle C_{L1;0 1}^{JM}.
\end{align}
The special cases $M=0, 1$ are useful. For $L=J$ and $M=1$ we obtain
\begin{align}
 Q \mathscr{Y}_{J1J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) \bigg\vert_{\theta = 0} =\sqrt{\dfrac{2J+1}{4 \pi}} |1 1\rangle C_{J1;0 1}^{JM}= \mathscr{Y}_{J1J}^{M}(\theta,\varphi) \bigg\vert_{\theta = 0},
\end{align}
i.e. $C_{J} = 1$. Similary, we consider the special case $\theta =0$ for the four constants $D_{J\pm1\,J\pm1}, D_{J\mp1\,J\pm1}$: Inserting $L=J\pm 1$ and $M=1$ we obtain
\begin{align}
 Q \mathscr Y_\pm^{1}(\theta,\varphi)\bigg\vert_{\theta = 0} &= \mathscr Y_\pm^{1}(\theta,\varphi)\bigg\vert_{\theta = 0}\notag \\
 &= \sqrt{\dfrac{2(J\pm1)+1}{4\pi}} |11\rangle C_{J\pm1 \, 1;01}^{J1}.
\end{align}
$M=0$ yields
\begin{align}
 Q\mathscr Y_\pm^{0}(\theta,\varphi)\bigg\vert_{\theta = 0} &= 0, \\
 \mathscr Y_\pm^{0}(\theta,\varphi)\bigg\vert_{\theta = 0} &= \sqrt{\dfrac{2(J\pm1)+1}{4\pi}} |10\rangle C_{J\pm1,1;00}^{J0}.
\end{align}
The following system equation follows:
\begin{align}
  1&=D_{J+1,J+1} + D_{J+1,J-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2J-1}{2J+3}} \dfrac{C_{J-1\, 1;01}^{J1}}{C_{J+1\, 1;01}^{J1}} \label{Dconsteqs:a}\\
  1&=D_{J-1,J+1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2J+3}{2J-1}}\dfrac{C_{J+1\, 1;01}^{J1}}{C_{J-1\, 1;01}^{J1}} + D_{J-1,J-1} \label{Dconsteqs:b}\\
  0&=D_{J+1,J+1} + D_{J+1,J-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2J-1}{2J+3}} \dfrac{C_{J-1\, 1;00}^{J0}}{C_{J+1\, 1;00}^{J0}}\label{Dconsteqs:c} \\
  0&=D_{J-1,J+1}\sqrt{\dfrac{2J+3}{2J-1}}\dfrac{C_{J+1\, 1;00}^{J0}}{C_{J-1\, 1;00}^{J0}} + D_{J-1,J-1}\label{Dconsteqs:d}
 \end{align}
Befor we write down, the solution of this system linear equations, we calculate the C.G. coefficients. There for we use the recursion formulas:
\begin{align}
 \label{cgrecursiona}
&c_+(J,M) C_{j_1j_2;m_1m_2}^{JM+1} =c_-(j_1,m_1) C_{j_1j_2;m_1- 1m_2}^{JM} c_-(j_2,m_2) C_{j_1j_2;m_1m_2- 1}^{JM}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
 \label{cgrecursionb}
&c_-(J,M) C_{j_1j_2;m_1m_2}^{JM-1} =c_+(j_1,m_1) C_{j_1j_2;m_1+ 1m_2}^{JM} + c_+(j_2,m_2) C_{j_1j_2;m_1m_2+ 1}^{JM},
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
c_+(j,m) = \sqrt{j(j+1)-m(m+1)}, \qquad
c_-(j,m) = \sqrt{j(j+1)-m(m-1)}.
\end{align}
Using the first recoursion formular, we obtain
\begin{align}
\label{cgcoffJ+1}
 C_{J+1\,1;M+1,-1}^{JM} &= \dfrac{c_+(J,M)}{c_-(J+1,M+2)} C_{J+1\,1;M+2,-1}^{JM+1} \notag\\
 &\hspace{0,2cm}\vdots \notag\\
 &= \prod_{n=0}^{J-M} \dfrac{c_+(J,M+n)}{c_-(J+1,M+n+2)} \underbrace{C_{J+1\,1;J+1,-1}^{JJ}}_{=1} \notag \\
 &= \prod_{n=0}^{J-M} \sqrt{\dfrac{J+M+n+1}{J+M+n+3}} \notag \\
 &= \sqrt{\dfrac{(J+M+1)(J+M+2)}{2(J+1)(2J+3)}}.
\end{align}
Similar with the second one
\begin{align}
\label{cgcoffJ-1}
 C_{J-1\,1;M-1\,1}^{JM} &= \dfrac{c_+(J-1,M-1)}{c_-(J,M+1)} C_{J-1\,1;M\,1}^{JM+1} \notag\\
 &\hspace{0,2cm}\vdots \notag\\
 &= \prod_{n=0}^{J-M-1} \dfrac{c_+(J-1,M+n-1)}{c_-(J,M+n+1)} \underbrace{C_{J-1\,1;J-1\,1}^{JJ}}_{=1} \notag \\
 &= \prod_{n=0}^{J-M-1} \sqrt{\dfrac{J+M+n-1}{J+M+n+1}} \notag \\
 &= \sqrt{\dfrac{(J+M)(J+M-1)}{2J(2J-1)}}, 
\end{align}
follows.
Again we use the recursion formulas to obtain $C_{J-1,1;01}^{J1},C_{J-1,1;00}^{J0},C_{J+1,1;01}^{J1}$ and $C_{J+1,1;00}^{J0}$:
\begin{align}
 C_{J-1,1;01}^{J1} &= \sqrt{\dfrac{(J+1)}{2(2J-1)}},\\
 C_{J-1,1;0,0}^{J0} &= \dfrac{c_+(J,0)}{c_-(1,1)} C_{J-1,1;0,1}^{J,1} -\dfrac{c_-(J-1,0)}{c_-(1,1)}C_{J-1,1;-1,1}^{J0} \notag \\
 &= \sqrt{\dfrac{J}{ (2 J-1) }}.
\end{align}
The remaining coefficient results from a symmetry property of the "Wigner 3-j symbols" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol):
\begin{align}
 \begin{pmatrix} J_1 & J_2 & J_3 \\ m_1 & m_2 & m_3 \end{pmatrix} = (-1)^{J_1+J_2+J_3}\begin{pmatrix} J_1 & J_2 & J_3 \\ -m_1 & -m_2 & -m_3 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
  C_{J+1,1;01}^{J1} &= (-1)^J \sqrt{2J+1}\begin{pmatrix} J+1 & 1 & J \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\notag \\
  &= (-1)^J (-1)^{2(J+1)} \sqrt{2J+1}\begin{pmatrix} J+1 & 1 & J \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\notag \\
  &=C_{J+1,1;0,-1}^{J-1} \notag \\
  &= \sqrt{\dfrac{J}{2(2J+3)}}.
\end{align}
Finally we obtain
\begin{align}
 C_{J+1,1;00}^{J0} &= \dfrac{c_-(J,0)}{c_+(1,-1)} C_{J+1,1;0,-1}^{J,-1} -\dfrac{c_+(J+1,0)}{c_+(1,-1)}C_{J+1,1;1,-1}^{J0} \notag \\
 &=-\sqrt{\dfrac{(J+1) }{ (2 J+3)}}
\end{align}
If we subtract the third from the first equation we have:
\begin{align}
 D_{J+1J-1} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2J+3}{2J-1}} \dfrac{C_{J+1,1;01}^{J1} C_{J+1,1;00}^{J0}}{C_{J-1,1;01}^{J1}C_{J+1,1;00}^{J0} -C_{J-1,1;00}^{J0} C_{J+1,1;01}^{J1}}
 =\dfrac{\sqrt{J(J+1)}}{2J+1}.
\end{align}
The last constatns are
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &D_{J-1J+1} &&= D^*_{J+1J-1} =\dfrac{\sqrt{J(J+1)}}{2J+1} \\
 &D_{J-1,J-1} &&= - D_{J+1J-1} \sqrt{\dfrac{2J+3}{2J-1}}\dfrac{ C_{J-1,1;01}^{J1}}{C_{J+1,1;01}^{J1}}= \dfrac{J+1}{2J+1}, \\
 &D_{J+1,J+1}&&=1- D_{J+1J-1} \sqrt{\dfrac{2J+3}{2J-1}}\dfrac{ C_{J-1,1;01}^{J1}}{C_{J+1,1;01}^{J1}} = \dfrac{J}{2J+1}.
\end{alignat}
Conclusion:
\begin{align}
S_{12} \mathscr Y_{J,0,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) &= 0 \\
S_{12} \mathscr Y_{J,0,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) &= 2 \mathscr Y_{J,0,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) \\
S_{12} \mathscr Y_{J+1,1,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) &=  - \dfrac{2(J+2)}{2J+1} \mathscr Y_{J+1,1,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) + \dfrac{6\sqrt{J(J+1)}}{2J+1} \mathscr Y_{J-1,1,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) \\
S_{12}\mathscr Y_{J-1,1,J}^M(\theta,\varphi) &= \dfrac{6\sqrt{J(J+1)}}{2J+1} \mathscr Y_{J+1,1,J}^M(\theta,\varphi)- \dfrac{2(J-1)}{2J+1} \mathscr Y_{J-1,1,J}^M(\theta,\varphi).
\end{align}